# jquery autocomplete passing parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete, active-directory

I need help to pass parameters through JQuery's autocomplete. I have an input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="searchName" id="searchName" placeholder="Nom et/ou prénom" />
```

inside a form. When you type, an jquery autocomplete function launches a search in Active Directory and shows result in the drop down list:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/SearchUserWhileTyping",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { name: $("#searchName").val() },
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#searchName").html(''),
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 4
        })
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#searchName').on('autocompletechange change', function () {
                $('#searchValue').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
            }).change()});
```

For now I could only do it after a form validation: form is validated -> I load the users found and their unique id -> click on one link and it shows the user info thanks to their unique id passed through. What I want to do is: If you click on one of the autocomplete choices, it directly shows the information of your user.

Here is the code for the search while you type:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchUserWhileTyping(string name)
    {
        ADManager adManager = new ADManager();
        List<string> lastName = adManager.SearchUserByName(name);
        List<string> splitList = new List<string>();
        if (lastName != null)
        {
            if (lastName.Count <= 10)
            {
                int inc = 0;
                foreach(string splitter in lastName)
                {
                    if (inc % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        splitList.Add(splitter);
                    }
                    inc++;
                }
                return Json(splitList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I use a splitter because another function allows me to search AD and returns several parameters (which will then be useful to immediately find a user by its unique id, that's my difficulty). 
This calls the following function:

```
public List<string> SearchUserByName(string name)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection);
                var sidInBytes=new byte[0];
                //anr permet de chercher tout utilisateur contenant "name"
                search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(anr=" + name + "))";
                //search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=User) (name=" + name + "*))";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
                resultCollection = search.FindAll();

                if (resultCollection.Count == 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach(SearchResult sResult in resultCollection)
                    {
                        if (sResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].Equals(null) ||
                            sResult.Properties["displayName"][0].Equals(null))
                            continue;

                        displayName.Add(sResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString());
                        displayName.Add(sResult.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString());
                    }
                }
                ldapConnection.Close();
                ldapConnection.Dispose();
                search.Dispose();
                return displayName;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Finally, when I have my list of users, I can click on their link and I load info about the user using this function:

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> GetUserInfoBySAMAN(string sAMAccountName)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection);


                search.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + sAMAccountName + ")";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSID");
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("accountExpires");
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
                result = search.FindOne();

                ///Conversion du SID en chaine de caractères
                var sidInBytes = (byte[])result.Properties["objectSID"][0];
                var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(sidInBytes, 0);

                String time;
                if (result.Properties["accountExpires"][0].ToString().Equals("0")|| result.Properties["accountExpires"][0].ToString().Equals("9223372036854775807"))
                {
                    time = "Jamais";
                }
                else
                {
                    ///Conversion de la date en entier puis en date
                    DateTime dt = new DateTime(1601, 01, 02).AddTicks((Int64)result.Properties["accountExpires"][0]);
                    time = dt.ToString();
                }

                string desc="";
                if (result.Properties.Contains("description"))
                {
                    desc = result.Properties["description"][0].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    desc = "Pas de description disponible";
                }
                userInfo = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("displayName",result.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString()),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("memberOf", result.Properties["memberOf"][0].ToString()),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("accountExpires",time),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("description",desc),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sid",sid.ToString()),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sAMAccountName",result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString())
                    /*lastName.Add(result.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString());
                    lastName.Add(result.Properties["memberOf"][0].ToString());
                    lastName.Add(sid.ToString());
                    lastName.Add(result.Properties["accountExpires"][0].ToString());
                    lastName.Add(result.Properties["description"][0].ToString());*/
                };

                return userInfo;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

That last function doesn't work if I change sAMAccountName by distinguishedName because apparently this attribute cannot be used like that. I want to use distinguishedName and immediately have my object.

So what I need is to search while I type, and if I select one of the proposed choices, validating the form immediately send me to user info page.

Thanks for your help, hope it is clear enough

**Edit** I added a 2nd script that can get the value of selected item, but I need the data passed through the controller

Comment: what about using chosen plugin, on change, get value selected, display what you want to display ?

Comment: I have edited my question. I added a script that, as you suggested, allows me to get the value selected. The problem is in the SearchUserWhileTyping method, I retrieve a list of names only, and if I add distinguishedName attribute, it's gonna show it in my list (which I don't want).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, `autocomplete` method has [`select`](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) event.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/SearchUserWhileTyping",
                type: "GET",
                data: { name: $("#searchName").val() },
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#searchName").html(''),
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item
                        }
                    }));
                },

               select: function(e, ui)
               {
                 //Just Example
                 $.get("UserController", {ID: ui.Id}).done(
                  function(data){
                  });
                 //Write your ajax post or get method
                 //that fetches user data directly as soon as 
                 //the item in list clicked
               }  
            });
        },
        minLength: 4
    })
});
```

Edit: I saw your edit, so that you can use your `GetUserInfoBySAMAN` function for ajax get request inside select event (instead where I wrote "UserController"), and you have work for binding return data to the inputs or labels as well.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this. Another thing is I pass a list splitList with only names in it, otherwise I'm gonna show IDs in my dropdown list. Any idea how to handle this in ajax? Say: I pass the full list, and in ajax I decided to chose one out of two ?

Comment: Ok I think this can work, when you write ID, is that for my distinguishedName?

Comment: ID was just an example, I saw that you only use `AccountName` either to filter users and get user data. Btw, if I were you I would create a DTO  object class to pass data between backend to client e.g; "UserInfo"  You can check [here](http://www.encodedna.com/webapi/aspdotnet-webapi-example-autocomplete-text-using-jquery.htm) what I mean

Comment: Ok thanks. Yeah I was thinking about that too, for example create a class with my properties to pass through right?

Comment: I did the DTO but still don't understand how to use the function you put :(